# How to start HTTP Server on all network interfaces in LoopBack 4

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have created a new application using LoopBack 4 cli. I want to start the application on all interfaces 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1.

How can I do that?

Also how to change port number of application starting?

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Application.html#constructor-configuration 
you can pass the `host` to your restapplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For LB4:

If you are using RestApplication, according to [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Application.html#constructor-configuration) and [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Server.html#configuration)

You can pass the host here:

```
const app = new RestApplication({
  rest: {
    port: 3001,
    host: "my-host"
  },
});
```

Or if you are using your own application which extends any Application you can just pass it to `super`:

```
export class MyApplication extends RestApplication {
  constructor() {
    super({
      rest: {
        port: 4000,
        host: 'my-host',
      },
    });
  }
}
```

If you are using LB3:
There is config file in `/server` folder called `config.json`.
There change the `host` to:

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/v1",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 5000,
  .
  .
  .
  "legacyExplorer": false
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: My application class looks like this export class MetisApiApplication extends BootMixin(
  ServiceMixin(RepositoryMixin(RestApplication)),
)

Comment: it's same. Just when instantiating the application push the `rest: {
    port: 3001,
    host: "my-host"
  }` as argument. as I did with the rest application

Comment: you can try it out by changing the port.

Comment: In the constructor, I added host and port the way you suggested, options.rest = { port: 30001, host: "0.0.0.0" }. The only difference is I want to bind my server to all the interfaces by specifying 0.0.0.0. But now the server got bound to "http://127.0.0.1:3001/ping"

Somehow, it is not getting bound to all interfaces that is 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to start the application binding it to the hostname of the OS. This is what I did options.rest.port = 5678; options.rest.host = os.hostname(); super(options)